# Is there any research to indicate programmers are/are not moving to a hybrid of functional and object-oriented?

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, functional-programming, object-oriented

I am converting the OCaml [Format](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Format.html) module which does I/O and maintains state in a record with mutable values. As such it is a good candidate for me to convert to pure [F#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), pure [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) and a hybrid.

Since this is a toss-up for me on the three versions, I am interested to know of any research papers that indicate that programmers may be moving to hybrid code of object-oriented and functional, calling one from the other, or staying with-in one programming family.

Note: I am asking for research papers not subjective answers.

Comment: See [The TIOBE Index](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html). Not a research paper, but valid nonetheless. Scala and F# are increasing in popularity (if you compare over a number of years – though I am going from memory).

Comment: Well, I don't know about programmers moving, but classic OOP languages seem to be moving to becoming hybrid by intoducing functional features. For example, C# and C++ did that.

Comment: Scala is out there, too, using both paradigms alongside each other and mingling them.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the 70's Smalltalk had some of the features being hyped as new in OOP languages, only done better.